# How to determine whether a given object is a mask

Tags: actionscript-3, mask

Apparently, in Adobe's wisdom, both the object being mask, and the masking object contain a "mask" property. This leads to a cyclical reference that prevents determining which is the actual mask and which is the masked.

For example...

```
var clip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
clip.name = "clip";
addChild(clip);

var boundary:Shape = new Shape();
boundary.name = "boundary";
clip.addChild(boundary);

clip.mask = boundary;

trace(clip.mask.name); // outputs "boundary"
trace(clip.mask.mask.name); // outputs "clip"
```

I've iterated through the properties of both `clip` and `boundary`, and there doesn't seem to be anything unique that sets them apart.  My first thought was to force a removal of the superfluous "mask" reference in `boundary`, however, that also sets the `mask` property in `clip` to null, thereby removing the mask.

My second thought was to check the parent relationship of a mask.  If the parent is the same as the object's mask, then the object in question is itself the mask.

```
var a:Array = [clip, boundary];

for each (var item in a) {
    if (item.mask == item.parent) {
        trace(item.name + " is a mask");
    }
}

// outputs "boundary is a mask"
```

Seems to work, and after checking the [API reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask) on masks, it's clear that when caching, a mask will **need** to be a child of the masked, however... it's also valid to have a mask at the same depth as the masked (I do this from time to time when a mask needs to *not travel* with the masked content).

For example...

```
MainTimeline ¬
    0: clip ¬
        0: boundary
```

... can also be laid out as ...

```
MainTimeline ¬
    0: clip ¬
    1: boundary
```

So, there's the conundrum.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" hack I've found so far is to run `hitTestPoint` on the objects (after making sure they have something to hit under the target). Masks do not appear to ever return `true` for a full pixel hit test. This seems to work in most basic situations that I've tested:

```
public function isMask(displayObject:DisplayObject):Boolean {

    // Make sure the display object is a Class which has Graphics available,
    // and is part of a mask / maskee pair.
    if ((displayObject is Shape || displayObject is Sprite) && displayObject.mask) {

        // Add a circle at the target object's origin.
        displayObject['graphics'].beginFill(0);
        displayObject['graphics'].drawCircle(0, 0, 10);

        var origin:Point = displayObject.localToGlobal(new Point());
        var maskLocal:Point = displayObject.mask.globalToLocal(origin);

        // Add a circle at the same relative position on the "mask".
        displayObject.mask['graphics'].beginFill(0);
        displayObject.mask['graphics'].drawCircle(maskLocal.x, maskLocal.y, 10);

        // No matter which is the actual mask, one circle will reveal the other,
        // so hit testing the origin point should return true.
        // However, it seems to return false if the object is actually a mask.
        var hit:Boolean = displayObject.hitTestPoint(origin.x, origin.y, true);

        displayObject['graphics'].clear();
        displayObject.mask['graphics'].clear();

        // Return true if the hit test failed.
        return !hit;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Obviously you'd want to cache the `graphics` in case the objects already have some, <strike>and it could do with something more elegant than casting as Sprite so that it can handle Shapes,</strike> but it's a start.

*Edit:* Accessing `['graphics']` lets this accept `Shape`s, but obviously isn't super efficient. I'm not sure what the best method would be, short of adding an interface.

Comment: Your solution is interesting, and indeed appears to work, however, I confess I don't fully understand **why** it works.  What's curious is that if `hitTestPoint` runs on a masked object with pixel flag set to true, it fails but only if a `beginFill` & `draw` operation preceded it.  If it's just testing at the point specified, then any object type would be feasible.  I can understand that a hitTestPoint would work on a visible object (not to be confused with property `obj.visible` since both mask and object retain a true value), but why it fails on an non-pre-`draw` object baffles me.

Comment: If I understand your question, the `graphics` calls are just there to make sure there are pixels to hit, so that a non-mask always returns `!hit == false`. If your objects happen to be opaque at 0,0 already, you can remove all of the `graphics` calls and this will return correctly. It's a horrible hack though, so I'd only suggest it as a last resort!

Comment: I've added some comments as I think I'm not explaining myself very well. Hopefully they help a bit! It's annoying that this can't handle every possible mask Class (`SimpleButton` for example), but I'm not sure how you could make sure those were opaque somewhere without `Graphics` or `addChild`.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification.  I'll have to wait till I get home tonight till I try this, but; what about proxying the original DisplayObject with a temporary shape, applying the mask to it, running hitPointTest, reverting the mask, and removing the proxy?  In theory, this would provide accurate mask checks for all object types.

Comment: Hm, there probably is some way to juggle things around that would work, but I can't quite get my head around it at the moment. You'd need to get both objects in the mask pair opaque in the same position to be sure something is visible.

Comment: Great solution. Very hacky indeed, but it works. It'd be good to understand how the player evaluates a mask when rendering, as I'd assume it needs to know which is the mask. I was hoping there was some other property setting that might differentiate them in some way, but wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, haven't run into this before. I wasn't aware of the cyclical reference.

If your masks are exclusively masks, I would suggest just incorporating that into your naming convention. For example calling it clipMask as opposed to boundary.

As noted in the comments, in the situation where the mask is on the same display list, you could use getChildIndex() to compare their position on the display list of the parent.

Typically in that situation I'll have the mask layered over the other display object. This is not enforced obviously, and I don't believe that it has any effect on the result of the mask visually. But it's easier to maintain for a large group than a naming convention.

Still not ideal obviously.

Comment: It's a workaround, but not an ideal solution.  This is for a code library to a larger project that has many programmers.  Everyone names their masks differently, so it would only work some of the time. :/

Comment: It's rather likely there is not an ideal solution here.

Comment: One step closer in that case is maybe to use `parent.getChildIndex(clip)` and `parent.getChildIndex(boundary)` and assume that the higher index is the mask. If everyone can get on board with ALWAYS having the mask higher on the display list, that would work.

Comment: Found this when researching about masks : http://www.actionscript.org/forums/archive/index.php3/t-184762.html - which is really relevant for you, if any of your masks are created in the IDE.

Comment: I reviewed the link you shared.  The two solutions I see are both related to determining visibility as a factor of intersection, however, neither provide the actual answer of which object produces the mask.  At least with rasterizing the intersection to an image and testing the prevalence of white, it appears you could conclude the test by moving one object to the other's opposite side and again run the test.  This would tell you which object matches those dimensions of visibility, but may prove computational costly if used frequently...

Comment: Also interesting is getChildIndex.  While not conclusive, the probability of a mask being added to the stage prior to the masked object is low, but still just "probably" correct, as it's perfectly reasonable to add the mask prior.  Furthermore, this doesn't take into account the shifting of object index when bringing things to the front with setChildIndex(a.length-1);  Still, combined with a point system (perhaps) one could score probability.  If one only used Shapes, or Bitmaps for masks, it would score higher than a user defined class, or common objects like MovieClips.  Still just a guess